# Creating a dataservice to communicate between c# api and frontend (angular)

Tags: c#, node.js, angular, api, edge.js

I need some help with this.

I'm supposed to create a plugin for a webpage in angular that communicates with an API written in C# which is already in a .dll.
What is the best approach to this?

I already created a `data.service.ts` with the following code to get data from the api:

```
import { Injectable, ValueProvider } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {
  edge : any = require('edge');

  constructor() { }

  getData(type: String, method: String) {
    var data = this.edge.func({
      assemblyFile: 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Siemens\Automation\Simatic OAM\bin\CC.CommonInterfaces.dll',
      typeName: 'CC.CommonInterfaces.${type}',
      methodName: '${method}'
    });

    return data(null, function(error, result) {
      if (error) throw error;
      console.log(result);
      return result;
    });
  }

}
```

I want to use the getData method to get the right data frontend with a button click, while also leaving the code as dynamic as possible.

Any advice on this?

Comment: you will have to hose the dll as an API somewhere instead of directly calling it.

Comment: API assumes that you're going to call it over http.  so i would look at 1) where to host the API, and then 2) the http client package to call it over http