# Calling an interface (API) in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, api, interface

I'm new to front-end, Angular, APIs, etc. and got a new task at work to create an UI plugin (in Angular) of our local GUI via API call for our website.

I'm given an interface (.dll) written in C# and need to somehow call and read from this interface with Angular. My Angular project has a client side and a server side.

Does someone know how to actually do this? How do I call the interface and how do I use the data in Angular?

My first try:

I created a data.service.ts on the client side and tried to use edge to call the interface. But this doesn't seem to work at all. Maybe because edge isn't compatible I don't know.

```
import { Injectable, ValueProvider } from '@angular/core';
import * as edge from "edge";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  constructor() { }

  getData(type: string, method: string) {
    let data = edge.func({
      assemblyFile: 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Siemens\Automation\Simatic OAM\bin\CC.CommonInterfaces.dll',
      typeName: `CC.CommonInterfaces.${type}`,
      methodName: `${method}`
    });

    return data(null, function(error, result) {
      if (error) throw error;
      console.log(result);
      return result;
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a dataservice to communicate between c# api and frontend (angular)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59664295/creating-a-dataservice-to-communicate-between-c-sharp-api-and-frontend-angular)

Comment: @paul unfortunately it doesn't. I don't know how to hose/host the API somewhere and then call it from there. I asked that question back then but couldn't find a (for me) helpful answer

Comment: If you want to host the web API in local side, you could refer to the following tutorials to host the web API on IIS. [How to Host ASP.Net Web API on IIS Server](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2b481f/how-to-host-Asp-Net-web-api-on-iis-server/) [Common way to deploy asp.net web api](https://forums.asp.net/t/2126695.aspx?Common%20way%20to%20deploy%20asp%20net%20web%20api%20) Besides, you could also host Web API in an Azure Worker Role: [Host ASP.NET Web API 2 in an Azure Worker Role](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/host-aspnet-web-api-in-